# Error: ./src/App.js Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

[image]

I need to perform this with Switch but its give above error
I found this above error then I replace Switch to Routes then I found this below error.

[image]

**App js**

```
import React from "react";    
import './App.css';
    import { Avatar, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core'
    
    import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
    import Chat from './Chat';
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    
    function App() {
      return (
    
        <Router>
          <Routes>
    
        <div className="App">
           
           <div className="App_body">
                  {/*Sidebar*/}
                  <Sidebar/>
                   <Route path="/">
                   <Chat/>
                   </Route>
                   
           </div>
          
        </div>
        </Routes>
          
        </Router>
    
        
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

**Chat.js**

```
    import React from 'react'
import { Avatar, Icon, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core'
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import AttachFileSharpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AttachFileSharp';
import MoreVertSharpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVertSharp';
import { Search } from '@material-ui/icons';
import './Css/Chat.css';
import EmojiEmotionsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/EmojiEmotions';
import MicIcon from '@material-ui/icons//Mic';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';




export default function Chat() {
    const{roomid} = useParams();
    
    return (
        <div className="Chat">
            <div className="Chat_header">
                <Avatar/>
                <div className="Chat_headerInfo">

                    <h3>Room Name</h3>
                    <p>Last Seen</p>
                </div>
                <div className="header_right">

                    <IconButton>
                    <Search/>

                    </IconButton>

                    <IconButton>
                    <AttachFileSharpIcon/>
                    </IconButton>

                    <IconButton>

                    <MoreVertSharpIcon/>
                    </IconButton>

                </div>
            </div>


            <div className="Chat_body">

          <p className="Chat_message ">
           <span className="Chat_name">Asif</span>

          Hello How are you?
           <span className="Chat_time">2:09pm</span>

          </p>

          <p className="Chat_message Chat_receiver">
           <span className="Chat_name">Asif</span>

          Hello How are you?
           <span className="Chat_time">2:09pm</span>

          </p>
          <p className="Chat_message Chat_receiver">
           <span className="Chat_name">Asif</span>

          Hello How are you?
           <span className="Chat_time">2:09pm</span>

          </p>
            </div>


          <div className="Chat_footer">

           <EmojiEmotionsIcon/>
          <AttachFileSharpIcon/>
         <form>
             <input type="text" placeholder="Type your message"/>
             
             <input type="submit"/>
         </form>
            <MicIcon/>
        

          </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[image]

Now this Above Error Occurs Actually I am creating WhatsApp clone for this I need to you Routes or Switch to change chat view accordingly. I also check index.js file their I am importing App.js file correctly. I dont have Idea to solve this error.

Comment: `Switch` was replaced by `Routes` in `react-router-dom` v6. Remove the import and fix what you are rendering inside `Routes`... only `Route` or `React.Fragment` are valid children of `Routes` component. You can't use `Router` alone unless you specify a navigation object, use one of the higher-level routers, like `BrowserRouter`. Also, in `Chat` there is no longer a `withRouter` HOC exported from RRDv6. If you still need a `withRouter` HOC you'll have to roll your own. I can help if you need this.

Comment: which `react-router-dom` version you are using? In v.6, the switch is replaced by the `Routes`.

Comment: @DrewReese , yah, its obvious. But still I wanted to make sure, if he can also include the version that he is using in his question for future references.

Comment: version is 8.1.2

Comment: Now this error occurs After applying Solution you given @DrewReese 
×
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

Comment: I added screenshot above error in Question last

Comment: I add complete code of both files Please check thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` was replaced by `Routes` in `react-router-dom` v6. Remove the import and fix what you are rendering inside `Routes`... only `Route` or `React.Fragment` are valid children of `Routes` component.

You can't use `Router` alone unless you specify a navigation object, use one of the higher-level routers, like `BrowserRouter`. The higher-level routers maintain their own internal history context and location state, i.e. so `pathname` can be read from a defined `location` object.

App:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

Also, in `Chat` there is no longer a `withRouter` HOC exported from RRDv6. If you still need a `withRouter` HOC you'll have to roll your own.

Chat:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Chat() {
  const { roomid } = useParams();
  return(
    ....
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply Now I get this Error 
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

Comment: I added screenshot above error in Question last

Comment: @ReactDev Seems `Sidebar` isn't declared/imported.

Comment: Sidebar js included in App js But same error

Comment: @ReactDev Other than `Chat` which looks to be a matching default export/import what else is `App` trying to render? Is that the complete code? Try commenting out all of the `App` render return and uncomment a component at-a-time until it breaks, then you'll know which component isn't imported correctly.

Comment: ok I am adding complete code

Comment: Raees I add complete code of both files Please check thank you.

Comment: @ReactDev So if that is all of `App` then try commenting out `<Chat />` and see if it still has error. If the error goes away, then try my above suggestion with commenting out all the render return of `Chat` and adding back in one component at-a-time to find where it breaks.

Comment: Now this error occurs
./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'Routes' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

Comment: @ReactDev Please verify what version of `react-router-dom` you have installed. From the project directory run `npm list react-router-dom` and report back.

Comment: I restart my computer and run project again and  replace routes with Switch Its know working. My react router dom version is 5.3.0